# Parse through an SVG file in vbs (vbscript)

Tags: xml, parsing, svg, vbscript

I'm trying to parse though an SVG file in vbscript. When using a normal XML-file my code is working but when using a SVG file no tags can be found. Is it possible to parse trough a SVG file or even manipulate it?

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")

xmlDoc.Async = False
xmlDoc.setProperty "ProhibitDTD", False
xmlDoc.resolveExternals = False
xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False

xmlDoc.load("pathToSVG/XML")

Set root = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("svg")

for each elem in root
msgBox elem.Tagname
Next
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XML File parsing using the VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809494/xml-file-parsing-using-the-vbscript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBScript, MSXML and Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1199794/692942)

Comment: Would help to see the structure of the SVG file, if you have elements in there from various namespaces they will need declaring.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your script works with SVG files if you use msxml3 by changing the first line to:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
```

Or

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
```

Comment: They are already using `Msxml.DOMDocument.6.0`, you suggesting they downgrade?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn’t the fix and it’s related to them not declaring the namespaces in the file. This happens with any complex XML structure in VBScript the MSXML needs to understand what namespaces an element comes from before it will load it.

Comment: Thank you, changing it to msxml2 3.0 worked for me!